# Convert Javascript code to ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to know if it is possible to convert some code Javascript and write it with ReactJS component

can someone help me please ?

Comment: React**js** is javascript?!

Comment: With ReactJS you use JSX which is transpiled into javascript. So you don't need to convert your javascript code. You may want to read some ReactJS documentation.

Comment: I think you mis framed the question. If I understood right you are looking for converting a javascript code or a function to react component or a class.

Answer (score 4):

## The older way

If your function is just backend code or scripting you can create a pass-through component or a container component

The component only does the script and then renders another component usually a visual component or presentational component.

```js
// React container component
import React from 'react';
import ViewComponent from './ViewComponent'

function thisIsPlainJs () {
   // get me some data from apiUrl
   const data = fetch(apiUrl)
   return data;
}

const Container = () => {
   // this calls the function and gets the result
   const someData = thisIsPlainJs();
   // the result can then be passed on to the view component
   // <ViewComponent/> doesn't have any logic just use the data to render html
   return <ViewComponent data={...someData}/>
}

export default Container;
```

```js
// React view/presentational component
import React from 'react';

const ViewComponent = (props) => (
   <p>{props.data.text}</p>
)

export default ViewComponent;
```

## The newer way

The modern pattern is to not have container components like the one above.

That logic will now live inside a hook and will use state hooks to store data.

```js
// React hook
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function useThisIsPlainJs() {  
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
     const dataRes = fetch(apiUrl);
     dataRes && setData(dataRes);
  });

  return data;
}
```

```js
// React view/presentational component
// - because we don't need a container component this here is NextComponent from above
import React from 'react';
import { useThisIsPlainJs } from './hooks'

const ViewComponent = () => (
   // this calls the hook and gets the data
   // if you noticed we don't need props because we assume that this comp if top of the tree
   const { data } = useThisIsPlainJs();
   // we render the data directly if it exists
   return <p>{data && data.text}</p>
}

export default ViewComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS components are generally written in JSX, it looks a little like XML, however if you wish you can write directly in JS.

If you'd like to know more about JSX have a read here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

In your build process you can integrate [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) (it works alongside tools like Gulp, Grunt, Webpack etc) which will allow you to compile your JSX into JS, you can also go ahead and use Babel to transpile ES2015/ES6 code.

Answer (score -5):

```
function addHyphen (element) {
  let ele = document.getElementById(element.id);
  ele = ele.value.split('-').join('');    // Remove dash (-) if mistakenly entered.

  let finalVal = ele.match(/.{1,3}/g).join('-');
  document.getElementById(element.id).value = finalVal;
```